Error en gestor de contextos en Python
Estoy mirando un ejemplo de gestor de contextos de un libro, pero al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    with FrozenDroid() as droid:
TypeError: FrozenDroid.__enter__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Pero el código está copiado tal cual aparece en el libro, y el libro está basado en Python 3.12.
Dejo aquí el código por si alguien sabe decirme donde está el error y como solucionarlo:
class Droid:
        def __init__(self, name: str):
            self.name = name
            self.covered_distance = 0

        def move_up(self, steps: int) -> None:
            self.covered_distance += steps
            print(f'Moving {steps} steps')

    class FrozenDroid:  # Gestor de contexto!
        def __enter__(self, name: str):
            self.droid = Droid(name)
            return self.droid

        def __exit__(self, *err):
            self.droid.covered_distance = 0 

    with FrozenDroid() as droid:
        droid.move_up(10)
        droid.move_up(20)
        droid.move_up(30)
        print(droid.covered_distance)

    droid.covered_distance  # distancia reseteada


Más allá del error (explicado por Candid Moe), si está copiado tal cual del libro y te aseguraste de que fuera exactamente igual, sin modificarlo, entonces, en mi opinión, el código ni siquiera fue ejecutado por los autores involucrados, ya que de otra forma se hubieran dado cuenta del error. Yo buscaría un libro o una fuente que haya sido revisada, especialmente si es tu primera vez en programación. Si existen más códigos sin revisar en el libro, te vas a terminar topando con más problemas como este, que te harán pensar "pero si lo hice como dice el libro".

En esta página está el mismo código. Copiandolo y ejecutándolo directamente aparece el error. Puede ser un typo del autor, pero si detectas más errores recomiendo cambiar a otra fuente.

El método __enter__() no tiene otro parámetro que self. Si quieres que actue sobre algún dato, tendrías que capturarlo en la inicialización de la clase:
class FrozenDroid:  # Gestor de contexto!
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")
        self.droid = Droid(self.name)
        return self.droid

    def __exit__(self, *err):
        print("exit")
        self.droid.covered_distance = 0

Demo
class Droid:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.covered_distance = 0

    def move_up(self, steps: int) -> None:
        self.covered_distance += steps
        print(f'Moving {steps} steps')


class FrozenDroid:  # Gestor de contexto!
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")
        self.droid = Droid(self.name)
        return self.droid

    def __exit__(self, *err):
        print("exit")
        self.droid.covered_distance = 0


with FrozenDroid('nom') as droid:
    droid.move_up(10)
    droid.move_up(20)
    droid.move_up(30)
    print(droid.covered_distance)

produce:
enter
Moving 10 steps
Moving 20 steps
Moving 30 steps
60
exit

Process finished with exit code 0

